# adding and removing bootstrap class on division on mouse button click in angular 7 using renderer

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular7

I'm new to Angular 7, was trying to implment a feature but got stucked.
There are three divisions namely left, right and middle. middle div contains 2 more divisions inside it and those 2 divisions contains button inside them. I have applied col-md-6 class to middle division and whenever I click on left button inside middle div, I want the left division to be hidden and change the class of middle div from col-md-6 to col-md-9 and If both left and right div's are hidden I want the class of middle div to change from col-md-9 to col-md-12. I have tried using Renderer2, using addClass() and removeClass(). It's working with hostlistener, whenever I click on host element. But I want this functionality to work whenever I click on button. If there is any other method achieving this, then please suggest whether using Elementref or renderer2.

```
home-page.component.html



**left division**

<div class="col-md-3 sidebar" #leftBar style="background-color: #F8F4F4;">
</div>


** middle div**

<div class="md-center col-md-6"  id="content" #content>

    **left button**


    <div class="btn toggle-sidebar-left"  #t1 appSideBar> 
      <mat-icon> {{!leftBarHidden ? 'chevron_left' : 'chevron_right' }} 
      </maticon>
    </div>


    ** right button **
    <div class="btn toggle-sidebar-left" (click)="hide()" #t1>
        <mat-icon>
            {{!leftBarHidden ? 'chevron_left' : 'chevron_right' }}
        </mat-icon>
   </div>

</div>

**right div**
<div class="col-md-3 sidebar scrollbar" *ngIf="!rightBarHidden" id="sidebar- 
  right" style="background-color: #F8F4F4;">

</div>
```

home-page.component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, Input, Renderer2, ElementRef, 
ViewChild, HostListener, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import {  Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SideBarDirective } from './appSideBar';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css']
 })
 export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  rightBarHidden = false;
  leftBarHidden = false;

  constructor(private router: Router, private render: Renderer2, 
          private el: Elemen Ref) { }

 @ViewChild('leftBar') LeftBar:ElementRef; // leftbar is variable for 
 accessing left div.

 @ViewChild('content') content:ElementRef; // content is variable for middle 
 div
 @ViewChild('t1') t1:ElementRef;  //t1 is variable for left button inside 
  middle div

 @HostListener('click')
 onclick() {
  this.leftBarHidden = !this.leftBarHidden;

 if (this.leftBarHidden)
     {
       const b = this.LeftBar.nativeElement;
       this.render.removeStyle(b, 'display');

      this.render.setStyle(b, 'display', 'none');

      const b = this.LeftBar.nativeElement;
      const c=this.render.parentNode(this.t1.nativeElement);
      this.render.removeClass(c,'col-md-6');
     this.render.addClass(c,'col-md-9');
    this.render.removeClass(this.content.nativeElement, 'col-md-6');
    this.render.addClass(this.content.nativeElement, 'col-md-9');


 }

 else {
       this.render.removeStyle(b, 'display');
       this.render.setStyle(b, 'display', 'block');
       console.log(b);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Use [ngClass] https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass and *ngIf https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: already tried that method, but not working.

Comment: in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpqt1u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html I put a simple example. I don't konw if it can help you :(

Comment: tried doing the one you've suggested, still doesn't worked  btw thanks..